# Given a number N, swap the two nibbles in it and find the resulting number

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this code i am getting invalid syntax error. Will you Please tell me my Mistake

```
class Solution:
    def swapNibbles (self, N):
        return((self.N & 0N0F)<<4) | (self.N & 0NF0)>>4))
s=Solution()
print(s.swapNibbles(43))
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is because of `0N0F`. That's not valid syntax for a number. If you want to specify a number in hex, the prefix is `0x`.

Another syntax error is mismatched parentheses in the expression being returned.

You're also referencing `self.N`, but you never set that attribute. `N` is a function parameter, not a class attribute.

```
class Solution:
    def swapNibbles (self, N):
        return ((N & 0x0F)<<4) | ((N & 0xF0)>>4)
```

You would use `self.N` in a solution like this:

```
class Solution:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.N = n

    def swapNibbles(self):
        return ((self.N & 0x0F)<<4) | ((self.N & 0xF0)>>4)

s = Solution(43)
print(s.swapNibbles())
```

Comment: Hmm, they were [told twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67045484/14265373) about `self.N` already, but yeah maybe third time's a charm :-)